# Как сделать чтобы функция хранила агрегатное значение и не использовалась в GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

```
SELECT  Cast (dateadd(hour, datediff(hour, 0, Call.Time_of_Call), 0) as time) 
AS TimeStampHour,Hotlines.Name,Count(Call.ID)
FROM Call, Call_Fixation, Hotlines
WHERE Call.ID = Call_Fixation.id_call
AND Call_Fixation.id_hotline = Hotlines.ID
GROUP BY Hotlines.Name
```

Есть таблицы: Call, Call_Fixation(id значения других таблиц хранит), и Hotlines. Мне нужно вывести значения как на картинке, но в месте где "13:00:00 Trevor Helpline 2" у меня разделяеться на 2 значения с 1(если добавить в GROUP BY Call.Time_of_Call), если же убрать Call.Time_of_Call из Group By то пишет что Call.Time_of_Call не хранит ни результата агрегованых функций и не используеться в GROUP BY 
[image: Нужно выводить такие значения]

Comment: вы вероятно в селекте проводите какие-то манипуляции, чтобы только часы остались в строке hour ровные. а группируете по исходному `time_of_call`, исходные то значения разные, поэтому и две строки остаются, в видите одинаковое

Comment: зы: прям так и пишет, что "не хранит значение агрегатной функции"? :)  суть ошибки там в том, что если вы проводите группировку, то обычные поля записываемые в селекте должны быть в списке  группировки, остальные - использовать агрегаты.

Answer (score 0):

если у вас будут 2 строки со значениями `13:01:00`и `13:02:00` то фактически это разные значения, вы по ним группируете, и получаете разные строки. А выводите в выборке только `13:00:00` для обоих строк. Поэтому и получается, что видите вы одно и тоже значение, но в разных строках.

Вам группировать надо по такому же значению каки в выборке. А просто убирая `time_of_call` из группировки вы нарушаете sql-синтаксис (хоть mysql и пропускает это мимо в старых версиях). Поэтому и получаете ошибку, что поля из select либо должны присутствовать в группировке, либо использовать агрегатные функции.

```
  select hour(time_of_call) + ':00', name, count(*)
  from t1
  ....
  group by hour(time_of call), name
```